# How do I create a class that would store an object?

Tags: java

I'm currently working on a library system that has 5 classes: Student, Library, LibraryCard, TextBook and College. And one of the objectives I've been set was to create

> "a field of class Library, which stores the Library object
>   representing the college library which the student joins". (in the Student Class)

Now I'm not very familiar with Java and any help or tips as to how I can implement an object onto a variable would be very much appreciated.

Thank You so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let us suppose you already have a Library class, with a constructor `Library(some parameters)` (your constructor may vary, or maybe you will be using the default constructor).

Then in your Student class you need something like:

```
private Library library;
```

As a rule of thumb, make the member variables private, though there may be exceptions.

Then you'll probably want to provide a method of student:

```
public Library getLibrary(){
   return library;
}
```

and maybe a

```
public void setLibrary(Library library){
    this.library = library;
}
```

then in your constructor for Student, you're going to want to initialize library. Presumably you're going to have a constructor for Library that takes like the library name, hours. whatever as parameters and sets Library member variables to be those. You'll then either want to pass an already created library to the constructor of student and say something like `this.library=passed library parameter;` or (more likely) pass parameters that will allow you to call your Library constructor from within your Student constructor and say: `library = new Library(parameters to Library constructor passed in to student constructor);`